# Gitlab CI docker image not accessible in local

Tags: spring-boot, docker, gitlab-ci, docker-image

when new push is done ci gets passed but when I try to access the docker build on my local, it does not

`sudo docker pull registry.gitlab.com/thomson-aequalis/springboot-docker-k8-gitci`

The error that I get on my local when above command is executed 
`Error response from daemon: Get https://registry.gitlab.com/v2/thomson-aequalis/springboot-docker-k8-gitci/manifests/latest: denied: access forbidden`

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
    image: docker:latest
services:
    - docker:dind

variables:
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay
    SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: gitlab-ci

stages:
    - build
    - package
    - deploy

maven-build:
    image: maven:3-jdk-8
    stage: build
    script: "mvn package -B"
    artifacts:
        paths:
            - target/*.jar

docker-build:
    stage: package
    script:
        - docker build -t registry.gitlab.com/thomson-aequalis/springboot-docker-k8-gitci .
        - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN registry.gitlab.com
        - docker push registry.gitlab.com/thomson-aequalis/springboot-docker-k8-gitci
```

[image]

Comment: How do you login to the registry before trying to run "docker pull"?

Comment: I did not login infact

Answer (score 0):

In your Gitlab-CI job upu login to the registry. You should do the same in local but with your own Gitlab username before pulling from the registry.